# Cytoscape.js and Angular 5 - not possible to use variables outside cytoscape scope

Tags: angular, angular5, cytoscape.js

Good morning, I would like to set value of 'test' variable after click of any node of graph, but unfortunately my variable is undefined in the event function. Is it any possibilities to get to 'test' function. 
Here is par of my code:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit { 
   public test: string = '';
   constructor() {}
   ngOnInit() {
     this.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        layout: this.initializeLayout(),
        style: this.initializeStyles()
     });
     this.cy.on('click', 'node', function (evt) {
        this.test = evt.target.id();
     });
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the code to use an arrow function. See below.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit { 
  public test: string = '';
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cy = cytoscape({
       container: document.getElementById('cy'),
       layout: this.initializeLayout(),
       style: this.initializeStyles()
    });
    this.cy.on('click', 'node', (evt) => { // <- CHANGE HERE
       this.test = evt.target.id();
    });
  }
}
```

Using the `function` keyword changes scope, so that will not work.